# PHP, sustituir palabras en un string

Tags: php

soy estudiante y una de las practicas de inicio es abrir un archivo txt, buscar una palabra clave, sustituirla con otra y escribir todo el texto modificado en un nuevo txt. Todo ello tiene que hacerlo una función, he creado el código pero no realiza ningún cambio, el texto se lee bien y se escribe en el nuevo txt pero sin modificar. ¿Algún alma caritativa que me ilumine donde he metido la pata?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Ejercicio 3 en PHP</h1>
    <?php

    function modificarTxt($archivoBase, $archivoModificado, $nombre, $nombreDos){
        $texto = file_get_contents($archivoBase);
        str_replace($nombre, $nombreDos, $texto);
        file_put_contents($archivoModificado, $texto);
    }

    modificarTxt("Quijote.txt", "Quijote2.txt", "Sancho", "Morthy");
    ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modifica la línea:

```
str_replace($nombre, $nombreDos, $texto);
```

Y escribe:

```
$texto = str_replace($nombre, $nombreDos, $texto);
```

No estabas guardando la salida de `str_replace()` en ninguna variable. Recuerda quee `$texto` se pasa por valor, no por referencia.

Comment: que tonto es cierto, muchisimas gracias, era exactamente eso

Comment: Usa preferentemente la versión *case-insensitive* de la función: `str_ireplace()`

Comment: si, también la agregue después, muchas gracias